# using Unallocated space when not adjacent to extended partition

Tags: boot, disk-usage, unallocated

I need to use the unallocated space without deleting the sda7 partition 
In deed the unallocated partition is next to swap partition

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   204799999   102296576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       204802046   415737855   105467905    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       204802048   302456831    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       302458880   318081023     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       318083072   415737855    48827392   83  Linux
```

The last partition is 750 GB 
when I try to make a new partition, it assumes it is primary (as other options ) are disabled, but does not accept 'Add' in GParted meaning that is not acceptable.

Can someone help?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. There's a megabyte to each side of the swap partition. Is that what you want to allocate? That's a tiny partition size (less than a cylinder by most modern cylinder definitions). If the /dev/sda3 doesn't extend to the end of the disk you can extend it by dragging the right edge.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions must be a single blob of disk blocks, so that the partition table can be read by old BIOSs. You'd have to move partitions around. I answered a similar question at [Add unallocated space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311105/add-unallocated-space-to-ubuntu/311160#311160) which should work for you