# Add unallocated space to Ubuntu

Tags: unallocated

I have a win7 installed. For Ubuntu, I shrink my hard disk and free 80G for Ubuntu installation.

Then I installed Ubuntu alongside win7 using the free 60G space, and leave another 20G free unallocated.

After installation. I want to allocate the 20G to Ubuntu. How can I do it?

Following is my system information:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
    Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
    /dev/sda2   *       81920    25563135    12740608    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3        25563136   513466367   243951616    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda4       513468414   930506751   208519169    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
    Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
    /dev/sda5       513468416   812931071   149731328    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda6       812933120   813322239      194560   83  Linux
    /dev/sda7       813324288   852383743    19529728   83  Linux
    /dev/sda8       852385792   891445247    19529728   83  Linux
    /dev/sda9       891447296   930506751    19529728   83  Linux
```

The 20G free space is after /dev/sda9. How can I add 20G to sda4 extended.

Comment: How are you trying to partition it and where are you partitioning it from: Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Thank you for help. with my study, I refined my question. I want to allocate my unallocated 20G space to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, BACKUP YOUR DATA. I really, really mean that.

Since partitions have to be contiguous, you'll have to move the free space to either end of `sda4` (did you really mean `sda4`, the Win 95 partition?

Boot from a Live CD containing `gparted`, and run `gparted`. Do NOT try to boot from disk and run `gparted` on the same disk.

Use `gparted` to move partition `sda9` up 20GB (to the end of the free space). This will put your 20GB free space between `sda8` and `sda9`.

Repeat moving `sda8`, then `sda7`, then `sda6`, and finally`sda5` up 20GB. This will put the free 20GB between `sda4` and `sda5`.

Using `gparted`, extend `sda4` to include the 20GB.

Now, all that's left is to inform Windows that it's disk has grown. I don't know how to do that, and this is the wrong place to ask.

Having the disk partitioned the way you do is sub-optimal. Read partitioning How-Tos, etc. [at the Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/), [at IBM Developer Works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-1/), [at ccfl.edu](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/partitioning.htm), and [at LinuxQuestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Hardware/A_Short_Guide_to_Partitioning_a_Hard_Drive_for_a_Linux_System).

The 'good' way (IMHO) to partition a disk is to have a few, not too big, partitions at the beginning of the disk (`/boot`, swap, foreign Operating Systems), then an "Extended" partition covering the rest of the disk, with the rest of the partitions allocated within it.

BACKUP YOUR DATA!